# How to subtract cell value if adjacent cell has specific text?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet of all my personal budgeting, and I've allocated different amounts to different categories (e.g. power bills, cars etc.) I want to have a cell that shows how much is remaining in each individual category.

For example, say I have 1000 allocated for power bills per year. I want a cell that has the formula of something along the lines of:

=1000-IFS(F2="Power",E2)

Where column F is the category of bill in text, and column E is the amount each bill was.

I want it this formula to apply for the whole column, instead of me needing to enter in each individual cell with conditions. Can someone help please?

I have tried:

=1000-IFS(F:F="Power",E:E)

But this only comes up with error messages.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

try in row 1:

```
=INDEX(1000-IF(F:F="Power", E:E, ))
```